# If ntp.conf file has more than one NTP server, which one gets synced?

Tags: rhel, ntp, ntpd

I have a VM for which the `ntp.conf` file has more than one server,
like

```
server 172.16.8.34
server 172.16.8.24
server 172.16.8.14
```

when I run `ntpd -qg -c /etc/ntp.conf`, which server gets synced?

Is there any command to see with which server my time is syncronised?

Comment: There's a lot of (mostly still relevant) information in the NTP FAQ. For example, [How is Time synchronized?](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo.htm#Q-ALGO-BASIC-SYNC)

Comment: @roaima I went through the link you shared...I am still not clear which ntp server gets synced...is it on order in which servers are present in ntp.conf file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
ntpstat
ntpq -c peers
```

In ntpq, the synced server is marked with `*`.

In newer OSes ntpd is being replaced with chrony, which synchronizes more quickly and is more suitable for virtual machines. With chrony you can check the status with

```
chronyc tracking
chronyc sources
chronyc sources -v
```